# Import functions on-the-fly without loading all "sibling" modules

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following package structure:

```
pkg/
    __init__.py
    f1.py
    f2.py
```

Each of the `fX.py` files contains a function with the same name as the file (e.g. `f1.py` contains the definition of `f1`). Inside `__init__.py`, I do the following:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

import importlib
import os

module_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)

for fn in os.listdir(module_path):
    fname, fext = os.path.splitext(fn)
    if fname != '__init__' and fext == '.py':
        m = importlib.import_module('.' + fname, __name__)
        globals()[fname] = getattr(m, fname)
```

With the above, I can import the functions like so:

```
from pkg import f1
```

And I can split the definitions of `f1`, `f2`, ..., in separated files. The problem here is that whatever the function I import (e.g. `f1`), the `__init__.py` will also load the other modules (e.g. `f2`).

Is there some way to "catch" the import instruction inside the `__init__.py` and load only the required module?

If there is a better way to achieve what I want than what I am currently doing, feel free to present it!

---

Full example:

```
# pkg/__init__.py

import importlib
import os

module_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)

for fn in os.listdir(module_path):
    fname, fext = os.path.splitext(fn)
    if fname != '__init__' and fext == '.py':
        m = importlib.import_module('.' + fname, __name__)
        globals()[fname] = getattr(m, fname)

# pkg/f1.py

print('I am in f1.')
def f1(): pass

# pkg/f2.py

print('I am in f2.')
def f2(): pass
```

Current behavior:

```
>>> from pkg import f1
I am in f1.
I am in f2. # Ko, f2 loaded...
>>> f1
<function f1 at 0x000000000270AF28>
>>> f2  # Ok, f2 not imported
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'f2' is not defined
```

Expected behavior:

```
>>> from pkg import f1
I am in f1. # Ok, only f1 loaded...
>>> f1
<function f1 at 0x000000000270AF28>
>>> f2  # Ok, f2 not imported
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'f2' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Python import only what you instruct it to import. The correct syntax here would be:

```
from pkg.module import object
```

Then if you remove all the code from `__init__.py`, the following happens:

```
>>> from pkg.f1 import f1
I am in f1.
>>> f1
<function pkg.f1.f1>
```

Comment: I know how the standard python import works, this is not what I am asking - I want to be able to import `f1` doing `from pkg import f1` (not `from pkg.f1 import f1`), but without having all module being imported inside `__init__.py`.